# Migrated Magento 1.9.X from one server to another but cannot login

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have migrated my magento instance from one server to another.

Here's what I did.

- I zipped my instance from original server but did not include download folder
- I also exported my mysql file and zipped it.
- On the new server, I extracted the zipped instance.
- I imported the database of my old server to my new server.
- I changed the web_secure and web_unsecure in core_config_data

Now, when I placed my admin URL like the one below

```
sample.com/ecommerce/admin
```

It will show Error 404, but if I tyled the URL below

```
sample.com/ecommerce/index.php/admin
```

It will show my admin page. On the Admin Page when I tried loggin in it will just reload and nothing happens except it was showing a key

so from this link **sample.com/ecommerce/index.php/admin** it will become **http://sample.com/ecommerce/index.php/admin/index/index/key/8e5a7db8b209a4d1ecf131805aaf10ed/**

Can please help where did I go wrong or if I did something I should not be doing?

Thank U

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check below points:

1) Check Htaccess file
2) Delete var/cache
3) System> Configuration> Web> Use Web Server Rewrites> Yes
4) Reindex php indexer.php --reindexall

Answer (score 0):

I Figured it out.

In the XML (app/etc/local.xml)

I replaced

```
<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

with this

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
```

and it worked.